# How solve the error "retrofit \n not found: limit=1 content=0d…"

Tags: retrofit, limit

I am developing with Java on Android, using retrofit library, at some point it gives me the error

> retrofit not found: limit = 1 content = 0d ...

and the connection is interrupted.

I am doing my tests at the moment with an emulator. Nexus_5_API_R_Android 10 emulator, API 29.

My Gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ni.iniser"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Libraries:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.1'
```

The implementation

```
private static Retrofit crearRetrofit(String baseURL) {
    Retrofit retrofit = null;
    HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(5,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(5,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(5,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(
                    new Interceptor() {

                        @NotNull
                        @Override
                        public Response intercept(@NotNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request original = chain.request();
                            Request request = original.newBuilder()
                                    .header("Connection","close")
                                    .build();

                            return chain.proceed(request);
                        }
                    }

            )
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build();
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    return retrofit;
}
```